# Table cells are not available for editing in FastReport

Tags: c#, fastreport

This issue occurred after update.

Cell without initial value after click not change state, i.e. they look like disable, but when I start fill cell start expanding.

[Gif](http://recordit.co/1iihIc8Fti)

But if fill cell by initial value, space for example, it's work fine.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and how did you solve it? Case with a space is not very pleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of FastReport, the `TextRenderType` property has been added for text fields. Since the cell is inherited from the text field, then this property is available to it.

Setting the value to `HtmlParagraph` solves this problem, but when exporting to excel turns some cells into pictures.

If there are many cells and manually changing the value is problematic, you can use the code:

```
var tableCells =
            report.AllObjects.ToArray().Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(TableCell)).Cast<TableCell>();

foreach (var tableCell in tableCells)
{
    tableCell.TextRenderType = TextRenderType.HtmlParagraph;
}
```

But execute it before the `Prepare()` method and after loading the document template.